# Attempting to change value of "total_price" variable but am getting "Undefined" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, increment, decrement

My goal is to build a shopping cart, which is able to calculate the total price of `n` items.

I am able to increment/decrement the quantity of each item, so everything is working properly. Except my `UpdateCartTotal` function - it shows `undefined` instead of the total price. How I can fix it?

```
    function getinput(event) {
      return event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".quantity");
    }

 // the Event Listener 
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if (event.target.className == "plus-btn") {
        increment(event);
        updateCarteTotal(event)
      }
      if (event.target.className == "minus-btn") {
        decrement(event)
        updateCarteTotal(event)
      }
    });

 // Increment function

    function increment(event) {
      var quantity = getinput(event)
      if(quantity.value<20){
         quantity.value++
        }
    }
  // Decrement function 
    function decrement(event) {
      var quantity = getinput(event)
      if(quantity.value >=1){
         quantity.value--
        }
    }

// the function to calculate the totale Carte price

    function updateCarteTotal(event) {

        const items=document.querySelectorAll(".item");
        var total_price=document.querySelector(".total_price");
        var quantity=getinput(event);
        var unit_price=document.querySelectorAll(".price");
        var total=0;
        for(item of items ){   
            total += parseInt(quantity.value * unit_price.value)
        }
        total_price.value=total.value
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is that you are trying to access non-existent properties from primitive types. Primitives types such as [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type) don't have properties you can access like non-primitive objects, so:

`total += parseInt(quantity.value * unit_price.value)` will not work as `quantity` does not have a property called `value`. Same can be said for `unit_price` variable. For the same reason, the following line will not work: `total_price.value=total.value`.

Also `total_price` is locally scoped to the function `updateCarteTotal`, so this will not retain a value for the duration of your program. You might be better off creating a global variable outside the scope of any individual function to store your cart total value.